# How to create a socket using WSASocket function in go programming language?

Tags: windows, go, winsock

Does anyone know how to create a SOCKET as returned by WSASocket() function in go programming language?

Using a normal syscall.Socket type syscall.Bind results in:
WSAENOTSOCK - Error 10038 - An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket. The specified socket parameter refers to a file, not a socket.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We don't use such low level API, we use net.Dial.  ex.

```
func main() {
        var (
                host          = "127.0.0.1"
                port          = "9998"
                remote        = host + ":" + port
                msg    string = "test"
        )

        con, error := net.Dial("tcp4", remote)
        if error != nil {
                fmt.Printf("Host not found: %s\n", error)
                os.Exit(1)
        } else {
                defer con.Close()
        }

        in, error := con.Write([]byte(msg))
        if error != nil {
                fmt.Printf("Error sending data: %s, in: %d\n", error, in)
                os.Exit(2)
        }

        fmt.Println("Connection OK")

}
```

Or, you could trace the code $GOROOT/src/pkg/net/dial.go